# Computing field values on save?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Quote(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)    
    votes = db.Column(db.Integer)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('author.id'))    
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime,default=datetime.datetime.now())    
    last_letter = db.Column(db.String(1))
```

I have a Model that looks like the above. I want `last_letter` to be the last letter of whatever the `content` is. Where should I place this logic so that it will occur every time a model is saved? I'm reading about Hybrid Properties and stuff and I'm not sure which way is the correct one to go.

Answer (score 1):

1.the Naive way: you can use sqlalchemy column `default` value to set something like:

```
last_letter = db.Column(db.char, default=content[len(content)-1:])
```

didn't check if that would actually work, guess not.

2.you can also do something like adding this **init** to the class:

```
def __init__(self,id,content,votes,auther_id,date_added):
    self.id = id
    self.content = content
    #yadda yadda etc
    self.last_letter = content[len(content)-1:] #or something similiar
```

3. or you could use "listen" to the "before insert" event and add this dynamically as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599376/object-based-default-value-in-sqlalchemy-declarative).
4. you can use sql computed column with an sql trigger (in the db) without sqlalchemy.
5. you can probably use a sqlalchemy mapper sql expression as a hybrid property, also I didn't try that myself, look [simple enough](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/mapper_config.html#mapper-sql-expressions) and probably is the most elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`last_letter` could be decorated with `@property` and defined

```
@property
def last_letter(self):
    return self.content[-1]
```

*Disclaimer: I just learned how to use decorators and am using them everywhere*

Comment: that wouldn't save it in the db.. but if db saving isn't needed this is a good solution